# Could not remove data from array using http request

Tags: javascript

I used this delete endpoint to remove data

This program was run using node js and express: 4.16.3

app.delete('/user/:Id',function (req, res) {

```
try{
    const index = users.findIndex(x => x.id == req.params.Id);
    if (index > -1){
        const delUser = users.splice(index,1);
        res.status(200).send({message:'User remove from the array',removedObject:delUser,data:users});
    } else{
        res.status(404).send({message: 'Invalid Id Provided'});
    }
}catch (e) {
    res.status(500).send({message:e});
}
```

});

Expected output status 200 and actual output was status 404

Comment: What output are you getting when you `console.log( index )`?

Comment: I got -1 as output when I used console.log(index)

Comment: Then the issue is either with `x.id` or the `req.params.Id`, i.e. they are not what you expect them to be. Perhaps there isn't a user with this ID? Maybe it's `_id`? In any case, the code is working as expected, you're gong to the `else` block when the ID can't be found.